# How Do I Split A String Using Multiple Delimiters (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to further split an already split string to further clean it up and remove unnecessary bits of info. This is a URL split by '/'

```
['https:', '', 'expressjs.com', 'en', 'starter', 'hello-world.html']
```

I would like to be able to make it:

```
['https:', '', 'expressjs','com', 'en', 'starter', 'hello-world','html']
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) can split a string on every match for your regex

```
>>> re.split('[/\.]', 'https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html')
['https:', '', 'expressjs', 'com', 'en', 'starter', 'hello-world', 'html']
```

`[/\.]` matches any forward-slash or period character

Comment: The backslash is not required when the `.` is inside `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
L = ['https:', '', 'expressjs.com', 'en', 'starter', 'hello-world.html']
L =  [subitem for item in L for subitem in item.split('.')]

print(L)
```

**Output:**

```
['https:', '', 'expressjs', 'com', 'en', 'starter', 'hello-world', 'html']
```